# How to subtract only the first number of a row in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

For example, say I have:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 6], [2, 45, 34, 56],[3, 8, 56, 45]])
```

I want to subtract 1 from the first number in all the rows. So it prints:

```
array([[0, 2, 3, 6], [1, 45, 34, 56],[2, 8, 56, 45]])
```

I have tried doing

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 6], [2, 45, 34, 56],[3, 8, 56, 45]]) -1
```

but, it subtracts from all the numbers rather than just the first one.

Comment: ... `a[:,0] -= 1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
a[:,0]-=1
```

`[:,0]` will access all values along the first axis, with the zeroth index along the second axis.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness:

your numpy 2D array looks like this:

```
[[ 1  2  3  6]
 [ 2 45 34 56]
 [ 3  8 56 45]]
```

what you want to do is subtract 1 from the first column.
This can be done by slicing the entire first column and subtracting 1 from its items.

in numpy you can slice columns like `array[:,col_num]` or rows like `array[row_num,:]` where the `:` means the `all the rows` or `all the columns` respectively.

so your solution is:

```
a[:,0] -=1
```

where you select all items of row with index 0 and subtract 1 from them.

I highly recommend you follow the basic and intermediate python tutorials of this [link](https://www.datacamp.com/) as they will make you familiar with these concepts and many others.
Hope this was helpful.